# AsyncStorage issue in react native expo

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I can't even tell you how many variations I have tried, tutorials and documentations that I have watched and read, I cannot transfer data from one page to another. Am using react native expo. I have this included in both pages: `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`.

This is the page I'm trying to set the data:

```
const ToyDetails = () => {
  const [savedName, setSavedName] = useState('')
  
  const addCart = async() => {
    setButtonText('ADDED TO CART!')
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('saved_name', savedName)
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  return(
    <View>
      <Text value={savedName}>{name}</Text>
      #{name} is because I am importing the name from a FlatList item
    </View>
  )
}
```

And getting that data from another page:

```
const Cart = () => {
  const [savedName, setSavedName] = useState('')

  useEffect(()=>{
      getData()
    }, [])

  const getData = () => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('saved_name')
      .then((value)=>{
        if(value!=null){
          setSavedName(value)
        }
      })
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text value={savedName} onChangeText={(value)=>setSavedName(value)}>{savedName}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I can post other variations I have tried if asked, I've tried adding it into a list and importing the list in the second page, I've tried to `JSON.stringify` the value `savedName` first (and `JSON.parse` it), I even tried doing it in the same way I did for FlatList. I'm not even getting any error messages.

Comment: Can you try adding async/await while reading the data while using getItem and let me if it works?

Comment: @BhishakSanyal it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: can you add your code on https://snack.expo.dev/ so we can check what's wrong

Comment: @Ragnar first time using it, hopefully this works: https://snack.expo.dev/@higaroth/fascinated-strawberries  . the setitem page is ToyDetails.js, Cart.js is the getdata page. just press login button to get in, ive disabled username etc.

Comment: can't see the screens in snack please update them

Comment: @Ragnar sorry, what do you need me to do? ive exited it and clicked the link, it worked for me so not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ToyDetails.js while saving **savedName** is empty. i changed to name and able to get it on **CartScreen**
https://snack.expo.dev/7ozHrsOBT check ToyDetails.j file

```
const addCart = async() => {
    setButtonText('ADDED TO CART!')
    try {
      console.log("savedName",savedName) //saved name is empty here 
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('saved_name', name)
    }catch(error){
      console.log('setitem didnt work')
    }
  }
```